# Hazelcast nodes refusing to join eachother

Tags: hazelcast

I have four VM's.  I am running hazelcast in "embedded" mode along with my application, attempting to use it for hibernate l2 cache.

I get mixed behavior when I attempt to start up different groups.  I think I'm having issues due to how the machines are subnetted.  The machines /sbin/ifconfig show that there are three subnets of 2 machines between the four nodes (node1 and node4 show two network devices other than loopback).

Mancenter is running on a fifth node.

Machine/subnet1/subnet2

node1   10.10.40.1   10.10.27.1

node2   10.10.42.1

node3   10.10.40.2

node4   10.10.42.2   10.10.27.2

So node1 and node3 share a subnet, node1 and node4 share, node2 and node4 share.

Behavior is very inconsistent, though node1 and node2 starting together seems to reliably form a cluster, as does node1 and node3.  Other combinations seem to enter split brain scenario, where it appears I have two or more clusters with the same name.

Querying our internal DNS the host names will resolve to the 10.10.40 and 10.10.42 IPs.

They have identical configurations.  I have tried turning on interfaces to 10.10.40.* and 10.10.42.* along with turning hazelcast.socket.bind.any to false.  Due to our deployment framework having identical configurations across a cluster is a high priority.

I have tried listing the nodes by both hostname and IP (the one that is resolved from nslookup of the hostname).  Listing by hostname is going to be a requirement from operations.

In some situations I have managed to get them forming a cluster, though migration fails because it complains that it cannot reach one of the nodes.

Of curiosity I have noticed that mancenter will sometimes identify a node as another, such as currenly I have node3 and node4 running (with node1 and node2's application shut down) and it is identifying one of them as node2.  I am wondering if this has to do with the fact that the nodes are running on VM's (one instance per VM).  I believe the hostOS is redhat and the VM is running centOS.

Am I on the wrong track thinking this is an issue?  What else can be causing this?

Comment: Without any deeper idea my first guess: firewall between the subnets?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue, though I'm not 100% sure what the root cause was.

The version of Hazelcast I was using was 3.8, but I carried over a configuration from 3.7.  At a glance the only difference was the schema being changed from "hazelcast-config-3.7.xsd" to "hazelcast-config-3.8.xsd".

I also upgraded mancenter from the 3.7 version to 3.8 version.  However I'm not sure that would have any affect.

Either way my four nodes are now up and talking to each other.  So if you come across this and are having a similar issue I'd recommend making sure your configuration version matches your deployed version.